# How to add SVG in a template string

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, svg, template-literals

How to add an SVG to a template string. I always get [object Object] message when trying to do so.

```
import ICONS from "./icons";

const Test = () => {
  const templateString = `add svg ${ICONS.threedots} here 
    does not work. It returns [object Object] instead`;
  return (
    <div>
        {templateString}
        It works if I add {ICONS.threedots} here
    </div>
  )
};
export default Test;
```

Comment: What is `ICONS`? It looks like it’s a react component which can’t be dumped into a template string

Comment: ICONS is an array with different SVG so I can map it in my react component. So there is no option I can add an SVG in a template string? I even try to add it like this but still the get the same error message. `<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-123" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
  <path d="M2.873 11.297V4.142H1.699L0 5.379v1.137l1.64-1.18h.06v5.961h1.174Zm3.213-.../></svg>`

Comment: Why do you need to put it inside a string when you can return it in the render jsx?

Comment: The template string is actually in the array I want to map so it doesn't work.